# ADAL.js with Multi-Tenant Azure Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, adal, adal.js

The sample code provided for using ADAL.js looks something like this:

```
window.config = {
    instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
    tenant: '[Enter your tenant here, e.g. contoso.onmicrosoft.com]',
    clientId: '[Enter your client_id here, e.g. g075edef-0efa-453b-997b-de1337c29185]',
    postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage',  localhost.
};
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(config);
```

This works fine, but I'm trying to allow access for a multi-tenant application - users from an organisation should only be able to sign in if the application has been granted access by their account administrator.

I've implemented the first part - allowing admin users to enable - [as per this example](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-multitenant-openidconnect/).

So at this point my application is listed in the third party's Active Directory.

I'm not sure what the correct settings should be for the tenant. I tried using 'common', but then it shows a dialog asking an individual user if they would like to grant access to the application, which is not what I'm looking for.

If I was making a straight MVC app, I'd continue on with the example above, using app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication on the server. But my app is a SPA, with Web Api backend, and I haven't been able to find a multi-tenant example for this scenario.

Answer (score 4):

The correct way of configuring your app for authenticating with any tenant, which is what you want in your scenario, is to use common.
The per-user consent is a provisioning consideration. If you want an administrator to consent for the app on behalf of the entire organization, you can implement the admin consent flow by triggering an authentication request and appending `prompt=admin_consent` to it. Provided that an administrator performs an authentication flow in response to that request, Azure AD will offer to the admin the chance to consent for the app on behalf of everybody in the organization.

Comment: Instead of you tenant (xyz.onmicrosoft.com) just use `common` as your tenant: `adalConfig: {
    tenant: 'common',
    clientId: '1068e0a3-...' // application id
  },`

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to configuring your app for authenticating with multiple tenant without using "common" is. You can ask user to input their email while starting the login process and pass the user type parameter like if user is using contoso.com then pass usertype = 0 else 1;
After declaring the two tenants and its client id, you can initialize the authContext by making it a function.

```
import AuthenticationContext from "adal-angular/dist/adal.min";

const adalConfig1 = {
    instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
    tenant: '[Enter your first tenant here, e.g. contoso.onmicrosoft.com]',
    clientId: '[Enter your first client_id here, e.g. g075edef-0efa-453b-997b-de1337c29185]',
    postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage',  localhost.
};

const adalConfig2 = {
    instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
    tenant: '[Enter your second tenant here, e.g. contoso1.onmicrosoft.com]',
    clientId: '[Enter your second client_id here, e.g. g075edef-0efa-453b-997b-de1337c29185]',
    postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage',  localhost.
};

export const authContext = (usertype)=>{
    if(usertype=== 0){
        return new AuthenticationContext(adalConfig1)
    }else{
        return new AuthenticationContext(adalConfig2)
    }
};
```

Use this authContext(usertype) to user login in function.