# Azure AD does not show User Consent page and returns AADSTS65001 on login, only for some AD tenants

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, adal, microsoft-graph-api

We have two different unrelated AD organizations (tenants). And an AngularJS website which wants to login users via their AD account (OAuth, same as sign in with Facebook or Google flow), or register with some pre-filled information from their basic profile. We use adal.js library, without adal-angular.js.

Each tenant has *its own single-tenant app* created in the "App registration" section.

#### Problem

Both login and register works perfectly with the first tenant's app. User signs in at `login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}` (let's call it "MS page" for brevity), sees the "User Consent" page, accepts giving permission, MS page redirects back to our website with id_token in the url, our app sends request for access_token and receives it successfully.

But for the *second* tenant's app it receives **AADSTS65001**: `#/error=interaction_required&error_description=AADSTS65001:+The+user+or+administrator+has+not+consented+to+use+the+application+with+ID+'ff1bb76e-7823-45a1-9950-b38fe8d3d0b4'.+Send+an+interactive+authorization+request+for+this+user+and+resource.&Trace+ID=...` when trying to get access_token after they signed in. **But "User Consent" page is not shown**, and there is no error message before this.

All interaction happens on the MS page, and it works differently in two different apps in two different AD organizations/tenants, which is a bit confusing.

**Same things in both apps:**

- our website code is the same in both cases (except for tenant id and client id ofc), it is deployed to the same url
- configuration of both apps is the same (cannot guarantee it, but we had a "shared screen" call, where we checked that manifest and all settings and permissions we know of have the same values)
- both apps were created from scratch in the new Azure portal, and we set only `oauth2AllowImplicitFlow: true` in manifest and Reply URLs, we did not change other settings
- both apps have only one permission set in Required permissions: Windows Azure Active Directory - "Sign in and read user profile" delegated permission

Our adal config is the following:

```
var adAccessTokenResource: = 'https://graph.windows.net' 
var adalOptions = {
      tenant: tenantId,
      clientId: clientId,
      resource: adAccessTokenResource,
      endpoints: { graphApiUri: adAccessTokenResource },
      //popUp: true // does not work the same way for both true and false
}
```

**Different things:**

One possible difference is that we have our website at `subdomain.{org-name}.com` where {org-name} is the same as the tenant-which-works name, so users have accounts `username@{org-name}.com` there. Can this be the reason?

In addition, for some accounts of the second tenant, `login.microsoftonline.com` redirects to the org-specific page to sign in the user. But for other accounts it does not, and error and behavior is the same in both cases.

After debugging with Fiddler we discovered that in both cases MS page sends the same `POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/login` request. But for the working app it returns 200 response with the User Consent page. If user agrees - the second request `POST /{tenant-id}/Consent/Grant` is sent, which returns 302 with id_token and redirects to our app, meaning that user has logged in. Our app asks for the access token on the redirect and this request works.

For the non-working app `POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/login` returns 302 redirect with id_token right away, *without showing the "User Consent" page*. So, we get a redirect after the first request. Our app asks for the access token and gets an error that consent was not given.

#### Question

What can be possible cases for the differences in the behavior?

Or should only multi tenant app be used? We wanted to make it work with single tenant app at first.

I am new to Azure AD. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an update, we've eventually did it with some ugly hack, but with new **msal** library (also from Microsoft, is an official replacement for adal lib), our AD login code got much smaller and better, and we did not have the problem.

So, use [msal.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) library instead of obsolete adal.js one

Answer (score 0):

According the answer of [ADAL.js with Multi-Tenant Azure Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36591868/adal-js-with-multi-tenant-azure-active-directory), the PM of AAD said that to implement `adal.js` for multip tenant, we can set the `tenant_id` to `common` and append the extra parameter `prompt=admin_consent` in login endpoint. I tried in a test code project, and which worked fine on my side.

Please refer to the following configuration in `adal.js`:

```
    var configOptions = {
        tenant: "common", // Optional by default, it sends common
        clientId: "<client_id>",
        extraQueryParameter: 'prompt=admin_consent',
        postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
    }
    window.authContext = new AuthenticationContext(configOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks! Hovewer, any info about why it does not work as a two single-tenant apps?

Comment: AAD's Authorization should follow the one of scenarios in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-authentication-scenarios, whose work flow cannot implement 2 different apps at same time. This is the limitation of OAuth v1. And about multi tenant integration, you also can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview.

Comment: Yes, but they are _not_ implemented at the same time. I change tenant id and client id in the code and redeploy it. So there is only one app used at any given time.

Comment: If so, it's not a mulit-tenant  scenario, I am sorry that I may cannot follow you, so what your question currently? Dose it solve your issue?

Comment: I have not tried multitenant and admin_consent yet, bc I do not have Global admin account, but I will. 

My question is about that AD works with the first tenant/client id pair, but when I replace them with the second tenant pair - it does not (details are in the question)

Comment: As by default, adal.js saves all the authorization info in `session storage` of browser, if you change the `tenant id` and `client id` but have not empty the data in `session storage`, it may get conflict. You can leverage the `Develop Tools` of Chrome, at the `Application` section to check all the data.

Comment: Thanks. But I did this. Also tested in Chrome Incognito mode (reopening winodw each time). This is not the case

Comment: Can the reason be that website `aaa.com` tries to use AD app registered for organziation `bbb.com`? `aaa.com` was added to Reply URLs.
But again, there is no error message that "consent cannot be shown"